# How do I make sure only int, not char, is input?

Tags: c++, function, loops, char, int

I wrote a function which shall only proceed if an `int` is input. If the `cin` fails, it shall do the `do{...} while()` once again until an `int` is input, not a `char`. 
My problem is, once I input a `char`, it ends up in an infinite loop. I can't tell why.

```
int syst ()
{
    int basisSys;
    bool opAga = false;
    do
    {
        cout << "Type the base you wanna calc. in" << endl;
        cin >> basisSys;
        if (cin.fail())
        {
            opAga = true;
        }
    }
    while (opAga == true);
    cout << endl << "You are calc. in " << basisSys << "system" << endl << endl;
    return basisSys;
}
```

Comment: when `cin` cannot read an `int` then the characters are still in the stream. You are looing for `cin.ignore`

Comment: Instead of reading an `int` from the stream, read a `std::string` using (for example) `std::getline()`.   Then check contents of the string to see if it contains data that would be read as an `int`.   If it does, read the integral value from the string.  If not, discard input, and continue.

Comment: By using the input operator `>>` you will make sure that the input is a number. Try to use it as a condition, for e.g : `while (cin >> num){//do your stuff}`

Answer (score 1):

It is important to ignore and clear the line since `operator>>` won't extract any data from the stream anymore as it is in a wrong format.

```
while(!(cin >> basisSys)){
   cout << "Bad value!";
   cin.clear();
   cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

Comment: Well that did work. But Why do I have to clear AND ignore? :)

Comment: If an error occurs then an error flag is set and future attempts to get input will fail. That's why you need  cin.clear()
Also, the input which failed will be sitting in what I assume is some sort of buffer. When you try to get input again, it will read the same input in the buffer and it will fail again. That's why you need cin.ignore